# Python on Linux remotely connect to a Windows PC to retrieve files

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have some files on a remote Windows system, that I need to retrieve. It's running Windows Server 2008 R2. I would like to retrieve those files to my Ubuntu System and I would like to do it using Python. I have gone through using wmi-client-wrapper, paramiko and wmic. None of them seem to work. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: *"None of them seem to work..."* is not very helpful for a problem statement. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Samba. This way you don't have to install anything on Windows.

- You can do something like `mount //windowspc/share /mnt`, then use Python to copy files from /mnt to wherever you want.
- You can call `smbclient` from Python as a system command

Alternatively, you can install `rsync` or `ssh` from Cygwin, or even something like FTP.

PS: this is not really a Python question, but basic filesharing.